# Set value of bound field to NULL using DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in a DataGridView that's based on a lookup table.

The ValueMember and DisplayMember fields are bound to string columns in the DataTable. All rows have a value for both fields - except for a special record where the value field is deliberately set to NULL.

However, when I choose this record an empty string is used instead of DBNull.Value in the DataTable bound to the DataGridView. This is happening at data entry time, before the data is pushed to the database.

I've checked out the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and DataGridView classes - there appears to be no simple way to customise this behaviour. Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did come up with *a* solution. Because the DataGridView is data bound, I implemented the ColumnChanging event for the DataTable. Sample code:

```
void Schedule_ColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if 
    ( 
        e.Column.ColumnName == "Site" &&
        e.ProposedValue is string && 
        e.ProposedValue as string == ""
    )
    e.ProposedValue = DBNull.Value;
}
```

This does the trick. Although I'd like to know if there is a solution that can be implemented at the DataGridView control level.

Answer (score 0):

I use a typed dataset to provide the values for the dropdown.  After filling values from the database I add *another* row to provide the null support.  The final lines of the method that populates the datatable look like this...

```
// Fill dt from datatable...
var nullRow = rv.NewRunDropDownEntryRow();
nullRow.SetIDNull();
nullRow.Title = "None";
rv.AddRunDropDownEntryRow(nullRow);
rv.AcceptChanges();
```

After that *it just works*!  The null value displays as "None" in the dropdown, you can easily update to or from null in the bound row.

HTH - Richard

Answer (score 0):

My lookup table in the database does not have a "None" entry. As a result a "None" entry was not allowed. A foreign key constraint prevented the entry of "None" in the child table containing the id corresponding to the lookup table.

My solution was to manually add a row containing "None" in form load (after the TableAdapter has already filled the table with the real rows from the database).

```
//' Add a 'None' row to allow the user to un-select a lookup item
//' The insert and update stored procedure translates a 'None' entry to NULL.
Dim newRow As MyLookupDataset.MyTableRow = Me.MyLookupDataset.MyTable.NewMyTableRow
newRow.MyID = "None" 
newRow.MyDesc = "None"
Me.MyLookupDataset.MyTable.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 0)
```

I used stored procedures for the Insert and Update statements of the TableAdapter. In the stored procedures I swallow the "None" entry -- that means if "None" is received as a parameter to the procedure I replace it with NULL. This allows the user to choose "None", but once saved the entry reverts to NULL.